# Dynamic plot with Evaluate on expression

Tags: dynamic, evaluation

I'm trying to make a make a plot of a table of expressions, which should be pre-evaluated (since they are infinite series with analytic sums). I'm able to make the plot normally with `Evaluate @ Table`:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sum[t^k/k! Exp[-t], {k, 0, Infinity, n}], {n, 1, 5}], {t, 0, 5}]
```

But when I surround it with a Manipulate it no longer works (there are errors that indicate *Mathematica* is evaluating the summation with a fixed value of t, which doesn't work at `t = 0, k = 0`).

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Evaluate @
    Table[Sum[ ((a t)^k)/k! Exp[-a t], {k, 0, Infinity, n}], {n, 1, 5}], {t, 0, 5}],
  {a, 0, 3}]
```

I know I can just evaluate the table and copy-paste, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

It can work with `a=0` too, the problem is that `a` is applied before closed form of the sum is calculated. We can force this:

```
DynamicModule[{t, k, tab, a}, 
 Column[{
   Dynamic@Plot[tab[a, t], {t, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 400],
   Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 11, 1}]
   }],
 Initialization :> {tab[a_, t_] = Table[Sum[((a t)^k)/k! Exp[-a t], {k, 0, Infinity, n}],
                                        {n, 1, 5}];
 }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With a few bells and whistles:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{plts},

  plts[a_, t_] =
   Table[Tooltip[
     Sum[((a t)^k)/k! Exp[-a t],{k, 0, Infinity, n}] // Simplify,
     StringForm["n = ``", n]], {n, 5}];

  Plot[Evaluate[plts[a, t]], {t, 0, 5},PlotRange -> {0, 1}]],

 {{a, 1.5}, 0, 3, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Bob Hanlon

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how to evaluate the sums without before `a` is set to `0`.  That can be done with `With`.  If you put `Dynamic` around `Plot`, then only the `Plot` will be updated when the slider for `a` is moved.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{plots = Table[Sum[((a0 t)^k)/k! Exp[-a0 t], {k, 0, Infinity, n}], {n, 1, 5}]},
  Dynamic @ Plot[Evaluate[plots /. a0 -> a], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]],
 {a, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Manipulate output]